# How can I do groupby in pandas by date?

Tags: python, pandas

I try many many times make a very simple transformation - I wanna do groupby for my pandas dataframe (by Date, and one more column), but after this action I see uncorrect date:
[image]
As you see on this screen, after transform appeared new date (2023-12-04). But its impossible, because i have not this date on my dataset!
[image]
Please, help me!

link to my dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h9SixsFJCoYIoXhBGhas3RQpY6_6r5S8/view?usp=sharing
link to my code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aNM5Fgn-QiI12y5h-lwTaTgxM3E1tN8Q/view?usp=sharing

I tryed to change type of data column 'Date' from object to datetime, but it wasn't help me(
I tryed pd.to_datetime(mrgd_df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y') too, but its unworked too((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime(mrgd_df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y'` doesn't work is because the date format actually is `%d.%m.%Y`.

Or you can use `pd.to_datetime(mrgd_df['Date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Thank you very mach!
Your advice is working!
Maybe I was very tied yesterday, iy was not difficult..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be when you do [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) without specifying the correct format.

There is a very big warning there exactly for that. You date is probably **April 12th 2023** (04/12/2023 in `MM/DD/YYYY`) which may be ambiguously interpreted as **December 4th 2023** (04/12/2023 in `DD/MM/YYYY`)

To ensure that, pass the exact format to `pd.to_datetime`

```
>>> mrgd_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mrgd_df['Date'], format='%m.%d.%Y')
```

Comment: Yea, I try it. But it gives the same result (as on screen two)

Comment: @ArtemGorbunov Sorry please read the message again and the warning you received